# Push from one array to another by reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference, pass-by-reference

Given this fiddle, does anyone have a suggestion as to how I might update the indices of array1?  Or more to the point, any idea how to make the indices of array2 references to indices of array1?

http://jsfiddle.net/y8rs56r3/

```
    var array1 = [
        {num:"one"},
        {num:"two"},    
        {num:"three"}
    ];
    var array2 = [];
    var i = array1.length;
    while(i--){
        if(i!=1)array2.push(array1[i]);
    }

    array2[0].num = "one updated";
    console.log(array2);
    console.log(array1);
```

Obviously, in this codeblock, array1[0] is not updated.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? By pushing as you have done, you have reversed the order of the elements (as well as excluded element `i` from `array1`). As it stands, `array1[2]` is the same object as `array2[0]` and is, in fact, updated in `array1` as well as in `array2`. If you don't want to reverse, iterate in a forward direction.

Comment: @TedHopp, that's correct.  array2 isn't just a clone of array1, or any given subset of consecutive indices of it.  In the actual application, array2's indices can be anything from 0 to all of the indices of array1.

Comment: Well, that doesn't answer my main question: what do you _want_ the behavior to be?

Comment: The desired behavior is for each index of array2 to be a reference to an index of array1.  Reversal doesn't really matter to me in this context.  Currently, if I update an index of array2, array1 is not updated

Comment: Your last statement is incorrect. Element `array1[2]` is updated, at least when I ran your fiddle.

Comment: Yep. As your loop is starting from the end the `index 2` of the `array1` is changed from `{num:"three"}` to `{num:"one updated"}`.

Comment: Yeah, egg on my face.  Clearly I somehow got mixed up with the array reversal and updated the wrong index.  You guys are absolutely right.  In the context of my application, I'm somehow losing reference when grabbing parts of arrays and sticking them into other arrays.  I thought I had tracked down the source of it, but apparently not.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

since your array is set of objects try like this:

```
  var array1 = [
              {num:"one"},
              {num:"two"},    
              {num:"three"}
          ];
       var array2 = [];
         for(x in array1){
                   array2.push(array1[x]);
                    }
          array2[0].num = "one updated";
          console.log(array2);//output  [Object { num="one updated"}, Object { num="two"}, Object { num="three"}]
          console.log(array1);// output  [Object { num="one updated"}, Object { num="two"}, Object { num="three"}]
```

Comment: Interesting.  Why does this work when the while loop doesn't?  Also, if I'm using this a lot in the context of a large application, potentially looping over large collections, should I start to worry about performance of the for in loop?

Comment: if you will assign objects they will reflect the changes to their references also.there might be an easy way but this is what i come up with.wait for some time and see if some other posts are coming.

Comment: to answer why it did not work in while, since you never assigned the first element of array1 to array2.